Why did Hutch drive backward?
In Wallace & Gromit: The Curse of the Were-Rabbit Wallace and Gromit are pest control professionals. They have a Rube Goldberg process of getting them out of bed at night and into the work van in the garage, so they can drive out to catch rabbits invading their customers' gardens.
During the course of the story one rabbit called "Hutch" takes on Wallace's characteristics and behaves like a miniature human Wallace, including being able to drive the van.
When Gromit gets entrapped by the story villain in a trap in the garden behind the garage of their home, Gromit is able to trigger the pest sensing system to get Hutch dispensed into the van, then Hutch drives the van in reverse through the rear garage wall into the garden so the trap Gromit is in can be banged open.
The usual process for Wallace & Gromit's leaving for work is to drive forward out the garage door to the front of the house. Had Hutch followed Wallace's usual procedure, Hutch would probably simply drive off forward to the front of the garage, and Gromit would still be trapped.
wallaceandgromit.fandom.com says Hutch

inadvertently backs up the vehicle

But Gromit seems to be depending on the backwards driving to get out of the trap.
What makes Gromit believe that Hutch will drive the van backwards into the garden?

Rabbits aren't the most reliable of drivers. I won't bore you with the details, but suffice to say that I learned that lesson the hard way.

Absolutely no help in the official novelisation; https://i.sstatic.net/JfMKRgq2.png

I don't think Gromit did believe that, or was expecting it. I think he was banking on Hutch driving normally to where the alarm was sounding from (i.e. the back garden), seeing Gromit in trouble, and opening the cage in a more conventional manner. Hutch just so happening to engage reverse gear, and the cage just happening to be in his path, was all a convenient coincidence.
If you watch the scene again, you'll notice a) Gromit only looks at Hutch, not the garage, suggesting he hadn't noticed the convenient positioning; and b) when Gromit sees Hutch reversing towards him, he's very visibly shocked and only braces himself a split-second before impact, as if he hadn't been expecting Hutch to do that at all.




This is a really good point, and makes me see the scene differently. I notice that had Gromit expected the reverse through the garage wall he would have been in a "crash position" already. As you say, he only ducks when the van is through the wall. He was not expecting the van to reverse. Thanks!
